# How can I write higher-order function to add methods to a given function?

Tags: julia

Let's suppose I want to write a function that accepts any associative operator ⊕ and adds methods to it such that I can replace any value with a function.  The semantics of these additional methods are as follows:

- If the operator is then applied to any two functions `f` and `g`, the result should be a function that first applies `f` and `g` (independently) to its arguments and then applies ⊕ to the results.
- If one argument is a function `f` but the other is any non-function value `x`, the result is a function that first applies `f` to its arguments and then applies ⊕ to the result and `x`.

I can express this in code as:

```
associative!(⊕) = begin
    ⊕(f::F, y) where F<:Function = (xs...) -> f(xs...) ⊕ y
    ⊕(x, g::G) where G<:Function = (xs...) -> x ⊕ g(xs...)
    ⊕(f::F, g::G) where {F<:Function, G<:Function} = (args...) -> f(args...) ⊕ g(args...)
    ⊕(f::F, y, zs...) where F<:Function = f ⊕ ⊕(y, zs...)
    ⊕(x, g::G, zs...) where G<:Function = x ⊕ ⊕(g, zs...)
    ⊕(f::F, g::G, zs...) where {F<:Function, G<:Function} = f ⊕ ⊕(g, zs...)
end
```

However, when I try to compile this function I get the following error:

```
ERROR: syntax: cannot add method to function argument ⊕
```

I know I can write a higher-order function that returns a *new* function / operator that is based on the one given.  For example:

```
associative(⊞) = begin
    let ⊕(x) = x
        ⊕(x, y) = x ⊞ y
        ⊕(x, y, zs...) = ⊕(x⊞y, zs...)
        associative!(⊕)
        ⊕
    end
end
```

If I inline the definition of `associative!` here then `associative` works just fine, and I can write:

```
⊕ = associative(+)
⊗ = associative(*)

f(x) = 3⊗x ⊕ 1
f(1) # 4
f(cos)(0) # 4
```

But I thought it would be nice to have a mutating version as well.  I assume re-writing `associate!` as a macro would work, but there really doesn't seem to be anything that would necessitate the use of a macro here.  So, is it possible to do this as a higher-order function and, if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to write your symbol but doesn't this get you someway towards what you want?

```
import Base.+

+(f::Function, g::Function) = x -> f(x) + g(x)

+(f::Function, x) = f(x) + x

# e.g.
new_plus = +(sum, sum)

new_plus([1,2,3]) # gives 12
```

Comment: Yeah, that's basically doing it manually, though, for a single operator (`+`).  You'd have to repeat the whole thing again for `*`, etc.  But anyway, the question is not so much about this specific case.  There are other uses one could think of for automatic the addition of methods to a given function.  I'm just wondering if this can be done with a higher-order function, or if some other approach (such as a macro) is required.

Comment: I see. I think a macro is required then because in this ```associative!(⊕) = begin
    ⊕(f::F, y) where F<:Function = (xs...) -> f(xs...) ⊕ y
    ⊕(x, g::G) where G<:Function = (xs...) -> x ⊕ g(xs...)
    
end``` the functions are only defined within the scope of the associative function, but I think you want it defined on the global scope in which case you need a macro.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going on here.  The first thing to note is that the first instance of `⊕(<args...>) = <body...>` will create a new function and bind it to `⊕`.  However, it apparently does not create a new binding for `⊕`.  I'm guessing that's why the error message mentions `⊕` is a function argument, but this is a red herring anyway — it would simply create a new function, rather than mutate the existing one.

Toward the end of [this thread](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/defining-a-function-inside-if-else-end-not-as-expected/13815), we see our [first hint at a solution](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/defining-a-function-inside-if-else-end-not-as-expected/13815/21).  In order to dynamically add a method to a function alias, we basically need to use the same syntax we'd use to define a callable object for some arbitrary datatype:

```
(::typeof(⊕))(<args...>) = <body...>
```

With this change, we get a different error:

```
Global method definition around ... needs to be placed at the top level, or use "eval"
```

A little further in the same thread, we see that this is due a change sometime after Julia 0.6, and that we [now need to `@eval`](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/defining-a-function-inside-if-else-end-not-as-expected/13815/26) these expressions.  Now that we're involving `@eval`, we need to keep the following in mind:

- We need to splice our references to `⊕` using `$⊕`
- The `$` in front of `⊕` seems to interfere with Julia recognizing it as an infix operator.  So we need to use the functional (prefix) notation instead.

Putting this together, we end up with something like:

```
@eval (::typeof($⊕))(f::F, y) where F<:Function = (xs...) -> $⊕(f(xs...), y)
```

If we really want to use infix notation instead, we can use a `let`-binding inside `@eval`:

```
@eval let ⊕ = $⊕
    (::typeof($⊕))(f::F, y) where F<:Function = (xs...) -> f(xs...) ⊕ y
    .
    .
    .
end
```